GooglePlaces SDK Breaks XCode Preview
I have a project connected to the FirebaseSDK which runs perfectly fine in Build, Simulator, Preview, and when Run on my iPhone 16 Pro.
However, I need to use the GoogleMaps SDK. When I install the package (https://github.com/googlemaps/ios-places-sdk) following the instructions from Google's documentation, my project breaks. It still builds successfully and will run on my device, but no files will preview anymore. This is huge headache when trying ot make incremental changes since I have to constantly run the project on my phone to see confirm my changes were successful as intended.
It seems like the package is not fully installing everything it needs. When I run the project i get the error message

    Cannot preview in this file
    Failed to launch *mybundleid*


When I view the diagnostics, I get a message:

    [Remote] CouldNotLoadInputStaticArchiveFile: Could not load static archive during preview: /Users/Brandon_1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<projectName>-edjwkkhkgvjnpgcgtmecmarculee/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GooglePlaces.a

    path: /Users/Brandon_1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<projectName>-edjwkkhkgvjnpgcgtmecmarculee/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GooglePlaces.a


I've tried several different troubleshooting attempts, excluding the arm64 architecture from debug, removing and reinstalling the package. Installing the Google Maps iOS Utils package and nothing seems to work.
Several help articles included instructions to download the XCframework or .a file manually and drag them into the project, I've attempt to do that as well but cannot without causing additional errors that indicate duplicate projects or files.
Would love to better understand how XCode packages its projects and handles package dependencies in order to resolve this, or if anyone has a solution, much appreciated!

I have the same issue. Not always though.
As a workaround, usually I just close Xcode, delete DerivedData contents and re-open the workspace.
It takes a lot of time after to rebuild and reindex, but it usually helps with this issue.

Have you tried the GooglePlacesSwift from the same package?

@taxiboatdriver What do you mean by have I tried it

Not a fix, but a workaround is to enable "Legacy Previews Execution":
Editor > Canvas > Use Legacy Previews Execution

Works, just tested it. But still what is the cause of the problem?

This did work for me, but I also would love to be able to address the root issue.

Man, that's it. Worked finally for me.
This is a long conversation I had with ChatGPT:
https://chatgpt.com/share/6745ec38-d61c-800e-91f2-6c8c9a1bbd68
Seems some strict constraint added on targeting CPU architecture in the latest Xcode. I could not figure out how to follow this path, but I think that the package developer is intended to do that, not us. That is why I think that this answer is the solution in this case, not just a workaround.

We removed Google Places iOS SDK from our project and switched to Google Web Service / Place API. We make simple URL requests for our needs and don't need the SDK anymore. You need to have a valid key though.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/overview
